# Assembly print a string

Tags: string, assembly, x86, dos

I'm having a problem printing a string which I read from the keyboard, if the string is the maximum length then it works but if I enter only 3 characters for example I got a blank black space, this is the code:

```
assume cs:code,ds:data

data segment
    sir db 12 dup (?),'$'
    mesaj db "Who`s your daddy?",13,10,"$"
data ends

code segment
start:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax
    mov dx,offset mesaj
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    mov bx,offset sir
    mov sir[0],11
    mov dx,bx
    mov ah,0ah
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset sir
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
code ends

end start
```

Comment: Please edit your question to format your code as code, rather than as a blockquote ;)

Comment: int 21h/0ah expects the first byte in buffer to be maximum characters, which you've done. Second byte will be number of characters actually read (after the interrupt). Text entered starts after that. Try `mov dx, offset sir + 2` before the int 21h/9. I'm not sure why that should cause the result you describe, but that's where your entered text starts.

Comment: Also make sure your string is terminated by a `$` at the actual end position. Simplest way to achieve that is to fill the entire buffer, so instead of the `dup(?)` use `dup('$')` or similar.

Comment: DOS? Wow. Well, good luck.

Comment: Well , I`ve tried with offset sir+2 but it doesn`t seem to work either , i dont know where the problem is ...

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `sir db 12 dup (?), '$'` to `sir db 12 dup('$'),'$'`, and your `mov dx, offset sir` to `mov dx, offset sir + 2` as someone else has suggested in comments, your code should work.

However, if you want to see the results clearly, you will need to print some newline characters.

This is because the `0ah` routine (string input):

1. echoes your input to the terminal, including the carriage return (`0dh`) it picks up when you press Enter, but not the line feed (`0ah`) that would move the cursor to the next line
2. puts all your input including the carriage return in the specified memory location, but again no line feed.

This means that immediately after the input routine runs, your cursor is sitting at the *beginning of the line you did your input on*, which still contains your echoed input.  So print a line feed character to make it go to the next line before you do anything else.

Next, when you print the string out, the carriage return at the end is picked up and the cursor is returned to the beginning of the line, but again there is no line feed. It is quite likely that whatever gets written afterwards (by your program, or any other program on the system) will overwrite what you have printed.  So, again, print a line feed to make it go to the next line first.

Printing a line feed should be as simple as:

```
data segment
....
    lf db 10, '$'
....

code segment
....
    mov dx, offset lf
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
....

    mov dx, offset lf
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
....
```